# AlarmManager - Won't go off when set to 10 minutes

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-intentservice

Basically how this code works is...it starts with an initial calculation and starts a service with an alarmmanager X minutes later which gets an ending calculation and determins the difference between the two. At the end of each alarm, a new alarm is set up for the same time interval. When I set my time interval to 10 minutes, the alarm doesn't go off at all.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the phones CPU going to sleep, since this is the issue that I've been trying to address for days with many different methods for writing this algorithm.

If anyone has a clue as to why this is, any help would be greatly appreciated as this is very important for the functionality of my program. As a sidenote, this code runs flawlessly for short intervals up to 5 minutes, as soon as I plugged in 10 I got nothing.

### From my service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // Set return value
    int retVal = START_NOT_STICKY;

    if (intent != null) {

        System.out.println("Service Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        // Set up context reference for getObject
        self = this;

        // Set up global intent reference
        theIntent = intent;

        // Get data
        getData();

        // Enter foreground state
        String title = "The service has been started...";
        String subject = "Service is running.";
        String body = "Monitoring your battery usage...";
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.theicon, title,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        if (notificationSounds)
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        else
            notification.sound = null;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity3.class);
        PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, subject, body, pendIntent);
        startForeground(1500, notification);

        // Calculate wait time (convert from minutes to ms)
        int waitTime = interval * 60000;
       // int waitTime = 15000; // Debug 15 second wait

        // Get initial battery
        int initialBatt = getBatteryPercent();

        // Debug
        System.out.println("Initial battery percent: " + initialBatt);

        // Get current time
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date dateNow = c.getTime();
        long timeNow = dateNow.getTime(); // Time in MS

        // Set up alarm manager to wait and then execute next step
        AlarmManager AM = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        svcIntent1 = new Intent(Service.getObject(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        svcIntent1.putExtra("timeToUse", timeToUse);
        svcIntent1.putExtra("interval", interval);
        svcIntent1.putExtra("rawTime", rawTime);
        svcIntent1.putExtra("initialBatt", initialBatt);
        svcIntent1.putExtra("sounds", notificationSounds);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Service.getObject(), 0, svcIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Set up the next alarm
        System.out.println("The current time is " + dateNow.
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
        Toast.makeText(this, "The current time is " + sdf.format(dateNow), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Date n = new Date();
        n.setTime(timeNow+waitTime);
        System.out.println("Next calculation will complete at " + sdf.format(n));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Next calculation will complete at " + sdf.format(n), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AM.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeNow + waitTime, pendingIntent);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

### onReceive inside my broadcast receiver class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
    if(intent != null){
        // Get app context
        context = Service.getObject();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm broadcast received.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Set up the intent
        theIntent = intent;

        // Get the extra data
        getData();

        // Do calculations and get new initial battery level for next alarm
        int endBatt = calculateHelper(initialBatt);

        // Set up alarm manager to wait and then execute next step
        AlarmManager AM = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent svcIntent1 = new Intent(Service.getObject(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        svcIntent1.putExtra("timeToUse", timeToUse);
        svcIntent1.putExtra("interval", interval);
        svcIntent1.putExtra("rawTime", rawTime);
        svcIntent1.putExtra("initialBatt", endBatt);
        svcIntent1.putExtra("sounds", context.notificationSounds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Service.getObject(), 0, svcIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get times
        long timeNow = dateNow.getTime();
        int waitTime = interval * 60000;


        // Debug stuff
        // int waitTime = 15000;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
        System.out.println("The current time is " + sdf.format(dateNow));
        Toast.makeText(context, "The current time is " + sdf.format(dateNow), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Date n = new Date();
        n.setTime(timeNow+waitTime);
        System.out.println("Next calculation will complete at " + sdf.format(n));
        Toast.makeText(context, "Next calculation will complete at " + sdf.format(n), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Setting the next alarm
        AM.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeNow + waitTime, pendingIntent);
    }
    else
        notify0(10,"ERROR", "ERROR", "Intent is null", true);
}
```

And in my manifest...

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </receiver>
```

---

### My New Code (Thanks to suggestions by Larry Schiefer)

I also figured out that even though a WakeLock is held by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver, if the OS were to close the service, it would be restarted WITHOUT a WakeLock. Therefore, it is sometimes necessary to acquire an additional wakelock for processing within onStartCommand. In my case, it is required.

In my service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // Acquire WakeLock
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Service WakeLock");
    wl.acquire();

    // Set up global intent reference
    theIntent = intent;

    if (theIntent != null) {
        getData();
        if (intent.getAction().equals("Start_Interval")) {
            doStart();
        }
        else if(intent.getAction().equals("End_Interval")){
            doEnd();
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.e("ERROR", "The intent is NULL inside of onStartCommand. Activity closed?");
        cancelAlarm();
        stopSelf();
    }

    // Release WakeLock
    wl.release();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

And my onReceive - Changed "extends BroadcastReceiver" to "extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver"

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
    if(intent != null){

        // Debug
        Log.d("Debug","Alarm broadcast received.");

        // Set up the global intent reference
        theIntent = intent;

        // Set up service context reference
        context = Service.getObject();

        // Get data from the intent
        getData();

        // Set up the new intent
        Log.d("Debug", "Setting up new intent with context: " + c + " and class: " + Service.class);
        Intent service = new Intent(c, Service.class);
        service.putExtra("timeToUse", timeToUse);
        service.putExtra("interval", interval);
        service.putExtra("rawTime", rawTime);
        service.putExtra("initialBatt", initialBatt);
        service.setAction("End_Interval");

        // Wake up the service and complete this interval's calculations
         startWakefulService(c, service);
    }
    else {
        context.cancelAlarm();
        context.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check that the manifest is pointing to the right receiver class; specifying the whole path might be a good start. I seem to remember having trouble with a different type of receiver because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Log` rather than `Toast` in your `BroadcastReceiver` to verify the broadcast was received. Once the system goes into a low power state, the RTC_WAKEUP will wake it up, but only for as long as your `onReceive` is executing. After that point, the system will release its wakelock for the alarm and the system can go back to sleep before the screen even comes on our your toast message is shown. If you need your service to actually do something based on the alarm, you will need to coordinate your receiver and service with your own wakelock to ensure the system stays up (see `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. What's confusing me is that according to the way I have this set up, my service really only just sets some initial values and then sets an alarm loop. The broadcast receiver is the only thing doing work from that point on, however I do reference public variables that belong to my service and call upon its methods to get a return result for use inside the onReceive.  Would these references and calls be interfered with, even though they are part of the onReceive method?

Comment: I've completely rewritten my code to use set/getAction in my service and a wakeful receiver like you suggested. Works perfectly. Thanks so much! Android is such a pain.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working.  Your original code's use of the `Service` was really only needed so you could set the notification in the status bar.  Beyond that the alarm could have been set from an `Activity`.  The interaction with regards to power management and alarms bites many, so don't get discouraged.  You'll also want to be very careful referencing public fields of your `Service` (or `Activity`) from within your `BroadcastReceiver` (or other component).  Each of these have separate lifecycles, so it's potentially dangerous to directly reference one from another.

Comment: Speaking of which, I currently have a static getter method in my activity that I do use to get a value in in my service. I've done this because it is a user-set variable that can be changed at any time via the GUI. Can I also just use putExtra with the same key string to replace the value whenever it's changed? Or will that create another key/cause other issues? What do you recommend for sending data changes to a running service?

Comment: Using extras in an `Intent` is definitely the "typical" way to go when passing data between components.  Each has an independent lifecycle and use of statics like this may yield strange results if you are not careful.